# How to ignore a file in the parent directory (and git root)?

Tags: git, gitignore

Given git root with:

```
/Guardfile
/local (dir)
/.gitignore
```

And a `.gitignore` in local, how to ignore the `Guardfile` from the `.gitignore` within local?

Don't want to change the `.gitignore` at the root because that is checked into git.

I tried:

```
../Guardfile
```

and

```
/Guardfile
```

and

```
./../Guarfile
```

git version 2.17.2

Use case (because someone will probably say "Don't do that".). It's pretty obvious but I don't want to change the project `.gitignore`. I keep all the files that don't belong in git in the local dir. But `Guardfile` needs to be in root dir.

Answer (score 6):

> someone will probably say "Don't do that"

Don't do that.

If you want to ignore a file but *not* modify an existing `.gitignore` that's part of the repository, put that in:

`.git/info/exclude`

This files contents are additive with the `.gitignore` at the base of the repository, and since its in your `.git` directory, it cannot be checked in.  Thus, it will be for your privately ignored files.